# What do double consonants specify in Esperanto?

Tags: writing-systems, phonology, esperanto

The Esperanto word for 'Finland' is *Finnlando*. What does the doubled consonant specify? The Esperanto alphabet is phonemic. Why are there two consonants? Is it gemination (which doesn't appear often elsewhere in Esperanto)?

Comment: Is it very rare for a root to have a double consonant and they are avoided. Most double consonants are just the result of affixation (mal-longa, mal-larĝa, ek-koni...), and agglutination of roots together (sen-noma...).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two questions (with answers) on the Esperanto stackexchange dealing with this problem (and yes, it is perceived as a problem even among Esperanto speakers):

- [Double letters in Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/double-letters-in-esperanto)
- [Asking specifically about Finnlando](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/3626/are-double-consonants-pronounced-distinctively-from-single-consonants-in-esperan)

The conclusion is: The double letter should be pronounced differently from the single letter, and it should be a true double consonant (not just a long consonant). *Finnlando* becomes hard to pronounce by these rules, and Esperantists are in fact shifting to the word *Suomio*.